# Technology behind retrogames.cc video games

Tags: javascript, html

What is the technology used in embedding the games on the retrogames.cc site?

I managed to see an HTML  tag, but I don't know how they are inserted, are they simulators of real games?

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on a game on this site, you get this pop-up menu:

[image: Pop-up menu over Sonic 2]

Clicking on "EmulatorJS v.0.4.24" takes you to [this site explaining the JavaScript video game console emulator they use](https://www.emulatorjs.com/).

So, it seems like the information about how this is done is at your fingertips. What is it that you need to know that's not explicitly described here?

Comment: Thank you, the information was there, just trying to double click on the game...